# Confirm order button does not works as expected

Tags: asp.net

I am creating an Shopping website as my project in asp.net but the problem am facing is that when a user clicks on confirm order button then data is not getting inserted in the database. To be more clear, This is working when i use the User created directly in the table but when i use the User created using registration form then its not working(i can login with this user id as data is inserted in the table). Also its not even providing any error message and is just redirecting to invoice page as i coded but without inserting data into the table.....Strange error i can ever imagine any help will be appreciated. Waiting for your reply. Thank You
this one i think maybe creating problem

```
    ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
      ArrayList ar1 = new ArrayList();
      ArrayList ar2 = new ArrayList();
      ArrayList ar3 = new ArrayList();
      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select Product_id,Product_name,Product_cost,Quantity from Cart where User_id='" + userid + "'",con);
      try
      {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
            ar.Add(a);
            String pdname = reader[1].ToString();
            ar1.Add(pdname);
            int pcost = Convert.ToInt32(reader[2]);
            ar2.Add(pcost);
            int q = Convert.ToInt32(reader[3]);
            ar3.Add(q);
        }
        pkid = (int[]) ar.ToArray(typeof(int));
        pkname = (String[]) ar1.ToArray(typeof(String));
        pkcost = (int[]) ar2.ToArray(typeof(int));
        pkq = (int[]) ar3.ToArray(typeof(int));
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error at second" + ex);
    }

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        for (int i = total-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            SqlCommand smd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Orders values('"+orderid+"','" + userid + "','" + name + "','" + pkid[i] + "','" + pkname[i] + "','" + address + "','" + pkq[i] + "','" + pkcost[i] + "','" + date + "','" + payment.SelectedItem.ToString() + "','Pending')", con);
            smd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so my probelm is solve. The solution for this was that i just remove try catch block and thats it its working as expected. Anyways i don't know yet what its not working using try catch block.